# ember computed property setdiff returns incorrect set

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a project in which I need to print the unique elements that are in one array, but aren't in another.

```
    MeterModifier.Meter = Model.extend({
        SLID: attr(),
        SPIDs: hasMany('SPID', { async: true }),
        premise: belongsTo('premise', { async: true })
    });

    MeterModifier.SPID = Model.extend({
        premise: belongsTo('premise', { async: true }),
        meter: belongsTo('meter', { async: true })
    });

    MeterModifier.Premise = Model.extend({
        meter: hasMany('meter', { async: true }),
        unusedSPIDs: Ember.computed.setDiff('SPIDs', 'meter.@@each.SPIDs'),
        SPIDs: hasMany('SPID', { async: true })
    });
```

Previously, I had set up this model so that (in Premise) meter was in a 'belongsTo' relationship with the meter model rather than a 'hasMany'.  This actually turned out to be incorrect, but unusedSPIDs returned the correct result.  At that point, I was using Ember.computed.setDiff('SPIDs', 'meter.SPIDs') .

Now, unusedSPIDs returns all of the SPIDs in the current Premise model, but does not take into account the spids in the associated meters.  So in short, it just returns all of the SPIDs for the current premise.  It does not throw any errors.  Does anyone have any ideas on why this is the case and how I might be able to work around it?  Thanks!

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zaqapevoko/3/#/meter/1

Comment: Ummm, I'm gonna need you to make a minimal test case. If you could add example data that would be great. http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: I've added a jsbin with the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can directly do this with a computedProperty macro. While there may be better ways to do it, you can always do it manually: http://jsbin.com/dumanamosu/1/edit

Comment: Hey @user1050838, I appreciate the sample code.  I noticed you modified the casing of my models, I assume to conform to ember conventions.  I also noticed that your example doesn't work if the casing is changed.  Do you know if there's a documented convention for these things somewhere?  I couldn't find it in the ember documentation, and I spun my wheels for some time trying to figure out why I couldn't get it working.

Comment: I've just changed my nickname :).  
Re the naming convention. Yes, this was intentional. Just checkout the examples in the [Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/).
The challenge that you face is in the async nature of the relationships. I would be myself interested if there's a better way to do this purely with computedProperty macros.